# FileStream и метод Seek

Tags: c#, filestream

Как при помощи метода `FileStream.Seek` считать часть массива байт от всего массива?

Ситуация такая, есть некий файл размером 177000 байт, где-то ближе к его концу есть 40 байт, которые мне необходимо считать. После этих 40 байт, есть ещё ~ 4000 байт.

Как считать участок размером 40 байт?

Comment: Открыли поток, спозиционировались на нужную позицию (FileStream.Seek), прочитали нужное число байт ([FileStream.Read](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netframework-4.7.2)). По ссылке пример, написано по-русски, даже не вижу смысла в поле ответ переписывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так например:

```
  byte[] dataReaded = null;

  using(var fs = new FileStream(...))
  {
    if(fs.CanSeek)
    {
      var endPartSize = 4000;
      var readSegmentSize = 40;
      fs.Seek(fs.Length - (endPartSize + readSegmentSize), 
              SeekOrigin.Begin);

      dataReaded = new byte[readSegmentSize];
      fs.Read(dataReaded, 0, dataReaded.Length);
    }
    else throw InvalidOperationException("Stream is not seekable");
  }

  return dataReaded;
```

Comment: Посмотрите где у вас объявлен dataReaded и где вы поставили return

Comment: и хорошо бы закрыть файловый поток

Comment: В вашем случае нет смысла проверять CanSeek: метод Seek и сам способен кинуть исключение.

Comment: Условие задачи так и напрашивает использовать Seek правильно: `fs.Seek(-(endPartSize + readSegmentSize), SeekOrigin.End)`. А если и работать с абсолютными значениями, то лучше уж Position использовать.